# Populate dynamic list with javascript

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I'm stuck on something.

I want to add a user's id to a database when Like is clicked, and display some user info in `<p id="likes_<? echo $item-id; ?>"></p>`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var user_id = "<? echo $user_id; ?>";
</script>

<? foreach ($items->result() as $item): ?>
    <p>This is the <? echo $item->title; ?></p>
    <p><a class="test" id="<? echo $item->id; ?>" href="#">Like</a></p>
    The following like this:
    <p id="likes_<? echo $item->id; ?>"></p>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

This is the js file which is also used to post. This is where I'm stuck. I don't know how to return the data for each individual post. I hard coded the id `$("p#likes_" + 8).html(data.content);` just to test it. Other than that everything works.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a.test").click(function() {

            $.post(base_url + "index.php/home/like", { user_id : user_id, post_id : $(this).attr('id') }, function(data)
            {
                    alert(data);
            }, "json");

             });

            function get_like()
            {
                    $.post(base_url + 'index.php/home/get_like', { post_id : $(this).attr('id')  }, function(data)
                    {
                            var post_id = $(this).attr('id')
                            if (data.status == 'ok')
                            {
                                    $("p#likes_" + 8).html(data.content);
                            }

                    }, "json");
    }

    get_wait();

});
```

I'm not posting the controller and model code but if needed I can add it. Using Codeigniter.

Comment: I assume your problem is on the client side? If so, please give us demo on jsfiddle.net

Comment: The end result will be to show the user info once the Like is pressed. But that's not my main problem now. I just don't know how to use `$("p#likes_" + 8).html(data.content);` to display data for each individual item.

Answer (score 0):

I dont sure if I am undestood you correct. I assume you would like fill up all your `p#likes_X` elements? If so, you should place all `<p>` in one root, use `$("p").each()`, split all `id`s by `_` and run your function `get_like($id)`.

Comment: yes, each item has an individual id. When someone clicks Like, the item id and user id is sent to the database. Then for each item, I want to get the user id that is associated with it. I don't get what you mean, can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

**Html5 data**

```
<a href="#" class="rate" data-dir="up" data-itemid="8">Like</a>
<a href="#" class="rate" data-dir="down" data-itemid="8">Dislike</a>
```

-

```
$("a.rate").live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = {
        'dir' : $(this).data('dir'), 
        'itemid' : $(this).data('itemid')
    }

    //do ajax
    //append :after
    $($(this)).after("<p id=" + data.itemid + ">" + callback + "</p>");
});
```

Grab the user id from your session ( presume they are logged in )

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I don't think I'm doing something right. I'm missing a step somewhere and can't figure this out.